# Wacom Intuos Draw CTL490DW Digital Drawing and Graphics Tablet compatible with Blender?

Tags: external-applications

I need to be sure before buying this Wacom tablet. Is it compatible with Blender for painting, 3D modeling, and blueprinting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a Wacom Intuos 4 and it works with Blender just fine, I just don't find it very helpful. It does everything that it's supposed to, but most things are easier with a mouse and keyboard.

...which is just to say that "it doesn't work very well" might mean it's not helpful, rather than that it doesn't function.

Answer (score 1):

Considering Wacom Tablets are basically mouse/pointing devices, there is literally no reason it wouldn't work. I have a Wacom Tablet myself, and it works excellently for painting, although for 3D modelling, a 3D mouse would probably be more useful.

Answer (score -1):

It is compatible, but it doesn't work very well. See [this thread](https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4731) on blender.org.

Comment: To be fair, most of those problems can be fixed in the Wacom settings.